# How to keep an object unique

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a static DataTable (with 80k records) in Common.DLL and that Common.DLL is referred by 10 windows services. So, instead of having 10 copies of that DataTable in the memory I need to have it as 1 copy and all the services pointing to that data source. Is this approach possible?

Comment: How much memory is this taking up? Are you sure it's a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: Or, are you seeing performance issues in loading data into your DataTable? (if so, there are other approaches that can be used to solve this, depending on where your data is coming from)

Answer (score 5):

Given that the services will at least be using different AppDomains, and quite possibly different processes, sharing the same data between all of them would be tricky.

I would personally suggest that you just don't worry about it - unless each record is actually pretty large, 80K records is still going to be fairly small.

You *could* potentially have an 11th service which is the *only* one to have the data, and then talk to that service from the other ones. But that's introducing a lot of complexity for very little benefit.

One way of potentially saving memory would be to use a `List<T>` for a custom type, instead of a `DataTable` - that may well be more efficient, and would almost certainly be more pleasant to use within the code. It doesn't help if you really *need* `DataTable` for whatever you're doing with it, but personally I try to avoid that...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) that is hosted locally and reads the 80k records into memory.

You would then define an API on the WCF service that contains methods appropriate to whatever calls your 10 windows services need to make.

Doing this would add a level of complexity to your solution that may well not be needed though.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton%5fpattern) pattern. Here's a [detailed tutorial](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) with C#.